# What does this set $A:=\mathbb{C}\setminus \{re^{ir} : r\geq 0\}$ look like?

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to prove that the set $A:=\mathbb{C}\setminus \{re^{ir} : r\geq 0\}$ is simply connected. The definition of simply connected is that any two curves that share end points have a homotopy.

I'm wondering what $A$ looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A$ is the complex plane with an [Archimedean spiral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_spiral) deleted from it.

Notice that in "$z = r \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} r}$" we have that $|z| = r$ and $\arg(z) = r$.  So by comparison with the standard form $z = r \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} \theta} = |z| \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} \arg z}$, we have $$\theta = \arg z = r  \text{.}  $$
In the form of an Archimedean spiral, this is
$$  r = 0 + 1 \cdot \theta \text{.}  $$